# How can a C program show the value of the largest possible unsigned long long?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Shouldn't the following program print out the value of 2^64 -1 as an integer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf ("%llu\n" , ( unsigned long long int ) ( pow (2 ,  8 * sizeof (unsigned long long) ) - 1 ) ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <limits.h>....printf("ULLONG_MAX = %llu\n",  ULLONG_MAX);`

Comment: @kaylum exactly XD

Comment: Instead of `8` you could use `CHAR_BIT` (to have the wrong result in a portable way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `pow` returns a `double`, usually a 64-bit floating-point type with 53 bits of mantissa. That is not enough to resolve numbers in the vicinity of 2<sup>64</sup> with a granularity of 1.

The next representable `double` value smaller than 2<sup>64</sup> is 2<sup>64</sup> − 2048 = 2<sup>64</sup> − 2<sup>11</sup>. 2<sup>64</sup> − 1 is still 2<sup>64</sup>, which is the nearest representable value. Converting that to `unsigned long long`, you get 0.

If you need the value of the largest possible `unsigned long long`, you can use `ULLONG_MAX` from `<limits.h>`:

```
printf ("%llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);    // need <limits.h>
```

The one's complement of `(unsigned long long) 0` – an `unsigned long long` with all bits set – should work, too:

```
printf ("%llu\n", ~0ull);
```

Comment: Interestingly, on x86_64 gcc it works (but not on clang): https://godbolt.org/z/W9c3r3.